# group a list by date while counting the rows values

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-visualization, big-o

This is the format of my data:

```
Date hits returning
2014/02/06 10 0
2014/02/06 25 0
2014/02/07 11 0
2014/02/07 31 1
2014/02/07 3 2
2014/02/08 6 0
2014/02/08 4 3
2014/02/08 17 0
2014/02/08 1 0
2014/02/09 6 0
2014/02/09 8 1
```

The required output is a:

```
date, sum_hits, sum_returning, sum_total
2014/02/06 35 0 35
2014/02/07 44 3 47
2014/02/08 28 3 31
2014/02/09 14 1 15
```

The output is for using [Google Charts](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart#Example)

For getting the unique date, and counting the values per row, I am creating a dictionary and using the date has the key, something like:

```python
# hits = <object with the input data>
data = {}
for h in hits:
    day = h.day_hour.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
    if day in data:
        t_hits = int(data[day][0] + h.hits) 
        t_returning = int(data[day][1] + h.returning) 
        data[day] = [t_hits, t_returning, t_hits + t_returning]
    else:
        data[day] = [
             h.hits,
             h.returning,
             int(h.hits + h.returning)]
```

This creates something like:

```python
{
  '2014/02/06' = [35 0 35],
  '2014/02/07' = [44 3 47],
  '2014/02/08' = [28 3 31],
  '2014/02/09' = [14 1 15]
}
```

And for creating the required output I am doing this:

```python
array()
for k, v in data.items():
   row = [k]
   row.extend(v)
   array.append(row)
```

which creates an array with the required format:

```python
[
 [2014/02/06, 35, 0, 35],
 [2014/02/07, 44, 3, 47],
 [2014/02/08, 28, 3, 31],
 [2014/02/09, 14, 1, 15],
]
```

So my question basically is, if there is a better way of doing this, or some python internal command that could allow me to group by row fields while counting the row values.

Comment: is your input sorted on date?

Comment: Then the answer below is the right approach; use `groupby`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input is always sorted (or if you can sort it), you can use [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to simplify some of this. `groupby`, as the name suggests, groups the input elements by the key, and gives you an iterable of (group_key, list_of_values_in_group). Something like the following should work:

```
import itertools

# the keyfunc extracts the key from each input element
keyfunc = lambda row: row.day_hour.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")

data = []
for day, day_rows in itertools.groupby(hits, key=keyfunc):
    sum_hits = 0
    sum_returning = 0
    for row in day_rows:
        sum_hits += int(row.hits)
        sum_returning += int(row.returning)
    data.append([day, sum_hits, sum_returning, sum_hits + sum_returning])

# data now contains your desired output
```